# The droplets size of different liquids?

Tags: experimental-physics

Does the size of a droplets depends on the size of the opening of the burette or pipette, would increasing the rate by which the droplets are falling would change the size of the droplets?

**Or** does it depends solely on the surface tension of the liquid itself, in which case the size of the droplets of the same type of a liquid would consistently be the same?

Comment: complicated problem!

Comment: See here: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5684891d7086d74497aeb71f/t/57e99bec5016e1900554e00e/1474927599087/c6sm00853d-2.pdf

Comment: @Gert I am not quite sure but I believe that producing a droplet with different size using the stated technique is entirely different from a free falling droplets. Where in the latter case the droplet is dropped after its weight exceeds the surface tension of the droplet surface.

Comment: In theory it is the state of maximum droplet size.